# Is this symbol available in latex?

Tags: symbols, code

[image]

This G symbol is ofter used to donate a collecttion of sets or a family of intervals.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are looking for `\mathscr{G}` from `mathrsfs`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\begin{document}
$\mathscr{G}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. I've taken the liberty of fixing a little typo.